# Why is (vocal) melody usually written in quarter notes?

Tags: melody, songwriting, lyrics

While writing melody, I was trying to stretch short verses into 16 bars by using too many whole and half notes, and now I think it was equal to having tempo at half speed. Most melody is written with quarter notes, is it wrong to stretch words into half and whole notes?

Comment: You can use any rhythm in a melody.

Comment: Fair enough, so maybe a 16 bar verse with mostly whole and half notes doesn't have much rhythm?

Comment: The premise of the question is untrue. Most melodies are not written with quarter notes

Comment: Have you not read a music book of children's songs or folk music? The syllables and words are almost always quarter notes with half and whole notes towards the end of the line. Are you implying that most melody has one word per measure consisting of whole notes?

Comment: I think @ToddWilcox suggests that various compositions use various note lengths. Just open a realbook and see. If your question is about specific children songs or folk music, please be more specific in your question

Comment: Simple melodies are a defining part of children's songs and much of folk music, thus simple rhythms are common, and straight quarter notes is about as simple as it gets.  The premise doesn't expand to all genres.

Comment: I edited my question to specify 'vocal' melodies. It seems long drawn out notes are tiring when it comes to a verse of words which is usually many many words telling a detailed explanation of something.

Comment: In addition to other comments, note that with singing (and other instruments too), *long written note values don't always get held out the full length.* The last note of "Camptown Races" would probably be written as a whole note, but would you absolutely insist that it be performed for exactly 4 beats? It could easily end up held on beats 1 and 2, but cut out on 3 as though a half rest were there, especially if there's another note coming up afterwards. And there's the question of "off on 1" versus "off on 4"...

Comment: It's going to depend a lot on the 'bpm' you want for a piece. It's true that the basic 'currency' is crotchets (quarter notes), as intimated by the 4 under the majority of time sigs, but that doesn't mean the tunes themselves will use mostly crotchets.

Comment: Perhaps we are working off of two different bodies of music. The vocal music that I’ve worked with over the last 20+ years has consistently included many eighth notes, dotted quarters and eights, 16th notes, grace notes, triplets, and half notes. I would say whole notes are less common in my personal experience but not at all unheard of.

Comment: Regarding children’s songs, I’ve covered several songs by The Wiggles and did not experience any difference in typical note lengths versus music intended for wider audiences. When teaching children I’ve found that a great deal of music for adults is both appropriate for and popular with kids, such as “Yellow Submarine” by The Beatles. If you’re talking about beginner music books for children to learn to play and sing, well then of course you’re going to find fewer different note values to help the beginners learn. If your question is about easy pieces for children, I suggest you edit that in.

Answer (score 1):

I'd tend to prefer stick with quarter-notes. In Editing Early Music John Caldwell (used to be the standard text on the subject). It deals with the conversion of mensural notation, about where we used to count in half notes, but now we count in quarter notes...
He strongly suggested turning the halfs to quarters, etc..
So equally to that, halves may look too old a style.
And quarters as melismas are old, I wouldn't advise.

Also from a music spacing point, quarters are better with syllables than eighths (with 1/8s you can have an accompaniment and that doesn't look as good if 1/8s are spaced wider to where they normally are.)
e.g. repeating long monosyllabic words to eighths like "straight", "through" or "twelve", just looks very ugly in my book.
Again nothing is set in stone, but that's from my point of view.

To give some examples of what I'm on about see below. I prefer B.
[image: difference between note grouping of eighths, quarters and halfs]

Comment: What is "better" and what is "usual" aren't necessarily the same.  Vocal music written in unbarred eighths has always made me crazy-- but so far as I can tell, at least in classical music, they are the norm.

Comment: Beamed eighths are the standard modern practice. Unbeamed drive me crazy too. I'm wondering if it's to do with sets of choral music and a choir wanting them, then they go back to the library and the use of these sets has go to be maximised, hence sets (even reprints) lasting a considerable time, and no change (modernisation) in the notation.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 classical music switched to preferring metrical beaming over syllabic beaming for vocal music sometime in the middle of the 20th century, I believe, but it drives me crazy since I grew up with older scores that used syllabic beaming.  Another reason to prefer syllabic beaming is that with metrical beaming you have to add slurs to show the text underlay, and many people mistakenly take the slurs as an attempt to communicate an articulation.

Comment: @phoog makes sense.  I have the bias of a piano player, who then took up composing.

Answer (score 1):

As Todd Wilcox mentioned, your question is founded on a false premise.  There's neither a historical norm (look up "origins of tenor") or a current norm where song notes are supposed to be written in quarter notes.

Here's just a sample.  I presume you will recognize most of these musicians, and will not claim that they don't know how vocal music is supposed to be written!

From Marriage of Figaro (Mozart), which is a vocal piece.  Note the eighth notes:

[image]

From Carmina Burana (by Orff), which is a vocal piece.  Note the whole and half notes:
[image]

From Missa Pape Marcelli (by Palestrina), which is a vocal piece.  Note the mix of various note lengths:

[image]

From Here Comes the Sun (by the Beatles), which is a vocal piece.  Note the use of eighth notes:
[image]